# Batch scripting: read lines and execute a command after every other line read

Tags: batch-file, dos

Suppose I have a text file like this

```
node1.log    
node2.log
node3.log 
node4.log etc...
```

I want to read each line by line and execute

```
alan.exe node1.log node2.log
alan.exe node3.log node4.log
```

etc..

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   if not defined line (
      set "line=%%a"
   ) else (
      ECHO alan.exe !line! %%a
      set "line="
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. File.txt will have your log file names.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('find /c /v "" ^<file.txt') DO SET NUM=%%G

SET /A NUM=NUM / 2

< file.txt (
    FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%NUM%) DO (
        SET /P LINE1=
        SET /P LINE2=
        echo mypgm.exe !LINE1! !LINE2!
    )
)
pause
```

Output

```
mypgm.exe node1.log node2.log
mypgm.exe node3.log node4.log
mypgm.exe node5.log node6.log
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Remove the word **echo** and replace mypgm.exe with the program you want to run.  The echo is just in there for the proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set args=
set n=2
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (file.txt) do (
    set args=!args! %%x
    set /a n -= 1
    if !n! EQU 0 (
        alan !args!
        set args=
        set n=2
    )
)
```